# In d3 chart the line look like it would go to 0 - how to avoid that?

Tags: d3.js

The curve in the d3 chart looks like it would be going to 0, (see attached picture). Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I want it to stop at the last value of the y axis.

[image]

```
// Draw graph line
g.append('path')
  .datum(prices)
  .attr('d', area(prices))
  .attr('class', 'area-bg')
  .attr('fill', 'url(#lightGradient)')
  .attr('stroke', '#15AA27')
  .attr('stroke-width', '1')
  .style('opacity', '0.6')
```

...

```
// For today's day indicate current pricing
if (this.day == Today) {

  // Draw the current pricing line
  g.append('line')
    .attr('id', 'limit')
    .attr('x1', innerWidth * this.markerY)
    .attr('y1', innerHeight)
    .attr('x2', innerWidth * this.markerY)
    .attr('y2', 1)
    .attr('stroke', '#484848')
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', 2.5)
```

....

```
  // Draw the current pricing label
  g.append('text')
    .attr('fill', '#484848')
    .append('tspan')
    .attr('x', innerWidth * this.markerY + this.labelOffsetY)
    .attr('dy', '10px')
    .text("Current pricing")
    .attr("font-size","10px");
```

....

```
  // Draw the current pricing label
  g.append('text')
    .attr('fill', '#484848')
    .append('tspan')
    .attr('x', innerWidth * this.markerY + this.labelOffsetY)
    .attr('dy', '22px')
    .text(this.currentValue + "/kWh")
    .attr("font-size","10px");
}
```

....

```
// Draw the y-lines
g.select('.grid')
  .style('stroke', '#79828F')
  .style('stroke-width', '0.5')

// Draw the box around the graph
g.select('.domain')
  .style('stroke', '#fff')
  .style('stroke-width', '0')
```

Comment: Hello! Could you share your code?

Comment: "Stop" in what way?  There obviously needs to be an edge of some kind.

Comment: stack overflow does not let me add all the code - it says "too much code, add more details" :-(

Comment: Your `area` function presumably generates an SVG path string; you then specify both its `fill` and `stroke` attributes. You might try to generate two path strings - one with `fill` but no `stroke` then one with `stroke` but no `fill`. You might need to modify the data by slicing a point off of each end for the `stroke`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to remove the “stroke” property of your area `.attr("stroke","none")`. And generate a line with the upper points of your area. https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#lines